# $f(t,x)$ defined and continuous implies $dx/dt=f$ has solution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(t,x)$ be defined and continuous for $a\leq t\leq b$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=f(t,x)  ,\\ 
x(a) & = x_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

has a solution on the interval $t \in [a,c]$ for some $c>a$.

you can divide $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal parts so $t_0=a,...,t_n=b$, and define a continuous function $x_n$ inductively by $x'(t)=f(t_i,x_n(t_i))$ for $t_i<t<t_{i+1}$ and $x_n(a)=x_0$.

Let $\bigtriangleup_n(t)=x'_n(t)-f(t,x_n(t))$

so $x_n(t)=x_0+\int_a^tf(s,x_n(s))+\bigtriangleup_n(s)ds$

but how do you use Arzela Ascoli theorem to find a convergent subsequence of $x_n$?